# Apps Script - Search value in array

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to search a value in an array of more then 8 thousand registers.

I've used indexOf but i think the array is to large and some pagination is occurring, so the value I know is in the array is not found.

Any ideas on how to get around it and search such a large array?

Below is my code.Its intended to search a value on an array and decide if it's not there it's new and should be added if it's found it should update/edit the value on destination.

That's an example of a value that i'm searching on the array [image array example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOX6P.png)

```
        function etlDIT() {
          var tabelaorigem = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Lista Chamados - DIT');
          var tabelasquad =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Squad N2'); 
          var data = tabelaorigem.getDataRange().getValues();
          var datasquad = tabelasquad.getDataRange().getValues();
          var novoValorStatusKanban = ""
          var finalizacao = ""
          var baseSistema = listabaseSistema()

          


          for (var i = 0 ; i < data.length; i++){
          
          console.log(data[i])
          
          if (i > 0) {


            for (var e = 0; e < datasquad.length; e++ ){

              if(e > 0){
                var chave = (datasquad[e][0]+','+data[i][4])
                var squad = pesquisaSquad(chave,'Squad x Projeto')

                if(squad != ""){break}
              }

            }



            var registroNovo = baseSistema.indexOf(data[i][0]);

            if (registroNovo == -1){

              if (data[i][6] == "Concluído" || data[i][6] == "Cancelada"){

                  novoValorStatusKanban = data[i][6] == "Cancelada" ? "Cancelado": data[i][6];

              }
              else {novoValorStatusKanban = ""}

              var atualizaStatusKanban = novoValorStatusKanban == "" ? "":novoValorStatusKanban;

                  finalizacao = "";
                  finalizacao = data[i][9] == "NULL" ? "": data[i][9];
              
              var usuarioDit = pesquisaUsuarioDIT(data[i][5],'Usuários')
              var vencimento = data[i][8] == "NULL" ? "": data[i][8];
              var linha = [data[i][0],data[i][1],data[i][2],data[i][3],data[i][4],data[i][5],data[i][6],data[i][7],vencimento,atualizaStatusKanban,"1000","",finalizacao,"","",usuarioDit,"Não","","","","",squad];

              adicionaChamado(linha);
           
            }

            else {
              
              if (data[i][6] == "Concluído" || data[i][6] == "Cancelada"){

                  novoValorStatusKanban = data[i][6] == "Cancelada" ? "Cancelado": data[i][6];

              }
              else {novoValorStatusKanban = ""}

              var atualizaStatusKanban = novoValorStatusKanban == "" ? "":novoValorStatusKanban;

                  finalizacao = "";
                  finalizacao = data[i][9] == "NULL" ? "": data[i][9];
              
              var usuarioDit = pesquisaUsuarioDIT(data[i][5],'Usuários')
              var vencimento = data[i][8] == "NULL" ? "": data[i][8];
              var linha = [data[i][0],data[i][1],data[i][2],data[i][3],data[i][4],data[i][5],data[i][6],data[i][7],vencimento,atualizaStatusKanban,"1000","",finalizacao,"","",usuarioDit,"Não","","","","",squad];

              atualizaChamado(linha);
              

            }


          }

          console.log('perc:' + (i/data.length)*100 + ' chamado: '+data[i][0])

          }


          }

        function pesquisaUsuarioDIT(valor,planilha) {
          var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(planilha).getRange('E2:E');
          var planilhaTotal = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(planilha).getDataRange().getValues();


          var textSearch = activeSheet.createTextFinder(valor).findAll();

          if (textSearch.length > 0) {

            var row = textSearch[0].getRow()-1;    
            var usuarioDit = planilhaTotal[row][0];

            return usuarioDit;
          }
          else {
            return "";
          }
        }


        function pesquisaSquad(chave,planilha) {
          var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(planilha).getRange('C2:C');
          var planilhaTotal = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(planilha).getDataRange().getValues();


          var textSearch = activeSheet.createTextFinder(chave).findAll();

          if (textSearch.length > 0) {

            var row = textSearch[0].getRow()-1;   
            var squadN2 = planilhaTotal[row][0];

            return squadN2;
          }
          else {
            return "";
          }
        }


        function pesquisaChamado(chamado) {


          const appAccessKey = '';
          const appId = '';


          const table = '';
          const action = 'Find';

          const properties = {
           'Locale': 'en-US',
           'RunAsUserEmail': ''

          };
          const rows = [{"Chamado": chamado}];
          
          const body = {
            'Action': action,
            'Properties': properties,
            'Rows': rows
          };
          const payload = JSON.stringify(body);


          const url = 'https://api.appsheet.com/api/v2/apps/' + appId + '/tables/' + table + '/Action';
          const method = 'post';
          const headers = {'ApplicationAccessKey': appAccessKey};

          const params = {
            'method': method,
            'contentType': 'application/json',
            'headers': headers,
            'payload': payload, 
            'muteHttpExceptions': true
          };

          const requestSimulate = UrlFetchApp.getRequest(url, params);
          let response
          try{
            response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
          }
          catch(err){
            Logger.log('err: ' + err);
          }
          finally{



          }

            var data = response.getContentText();
            var resultListagem = JSON.parse(data);

          return resultListagem;

        }

        function adicionaChamado(linha) {


          const appAccessKey = '';
          const appId = '';


          const table = '';
          const action = 'Add';

          const properties = {
           'Locale': 'en-US',
           'RunAsUserEmail': ''

          };
          const rows = [{"Chamado": linha[0],
                         "Título": linha[1],
                         "Entidade":linha[2],
                         "Sistemas":linha[3],
                         "Projeto":linha[4],
                         "Solicitante":linha[5],
                         "Status":linha[6],
                         "Criação":linha[7],
                         "Vencimento":linha[8],
                         "Status Kanban":linha[9],
                         "Prioridade":linha[10],
                         "Analista Cliente":linha[15],
                         "Chamado Triado":linha[16],
                         "Squad N2":linha[21]
                        },
                        ];
          
          const body = {
            'Action': action,
            'Properties': properties,
            'Rows': rows
          };
          const payload = JSON.stringify(body);


          const url = 'https://api.appsheet.com/api/v2/apps/' + appId + '/tables/' + table + '/Action';
          const method = 'post';
          const headers = {'ApplicationAccessKey': appAccessKey};

          const params = {
            'method': method,
            'contentType': 'application/json',
            'headers': headers,
            'payload': payload, 
            'muteHttpExceptions': true
          };

          const requestSimulate = UrlFetchApp.getRequest(url, params);
          let response
          try{
            response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
          }
          catch(err){
            Logger.log('err: ' + err);
          }
          finally{
            Logger.log ('requestSimulate:');
            Logger.log (requestSimulate);
            Logger.log ('response: ' + response);
          }

        }


        function atualizaChamado(linha) {


          const appAccessKey = '';
          const appId = '';


          const table = '';
          const action = 'Edit';

          const properties = {
           'Locale': 'en-US',
           'RunAsUserEmail': ''

          };
          const rows = [{"Chamado": linha[0],
                         "Projeto":linha[4],
                         "Status":linha[6],
                         "Squad N2":linha[21]
                        },
                        ];
          
          const body = {
            'Action': action,
            'Properties': properties,
            'Rows': rows
          };
          const payload = JSON.stringify(body);


          const url = 'https://api.appsheet.com/api/v2/apps/' + appId + '/tables/' + table + '/Action';
          const method = 'post';
          const headers = {'ApplicationAccessKey': appAccessKey};

          const params = {
            'method': method,
            'contentType': 'application/json',
            'headers': headers,
            'payload': payload, 
            'muteHttpExceptions': true
          };

          const requestSimulate = UrlFetchApp.getRequest(url, params);
          let response
          try{
            response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
          }
          catch(err){
            Logger.log('err: ' + err);
          }
          finally{

          }

        }


        function listabaseSistema() {


          const appAccessKey = '';
          const appId = '';


          const table = '';
          const action = 'Find';

          const properties = {
           'Locale': 'en-US',
           'RunAsUserEmail': ''

          };
          const rows = [];
          
          const body = {
            'Action': action,
            'Properties': properties,
            'Rows': rows
          };
          const payload = JSON.stringify(body);


          const url = 'https://api.appsheet.com/api/v2/apps/' + appId + '/tables/' + table + '/Action';
          const method = 'post';
          const headers = {'ApplicationAccessKey': appAccessKey};

          const params = {
            'method': method,
            'contentType': 'application/json',
            'headers': headers,
            'payload': payload, 
            'muteHttpExceptions': true
          };

          const requestSimulate = UrlFetchApp.getRequest(url, params);
          let response
          try{
            response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
          }
          catch(err){
            Logger.log('err: ' + err);
          }
          finally{



          }

            var data = response.getContentText();
            var resultListagem = JSON.parse(data);

          return resultListagem;

        }
```

Comment: Perhaps break it into smaller arrays

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please provide a sample array of `baseSistema`? I suspect that your array is in 2D or more?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  I've have use the indexOf() method with arrays greater than 15000.

Comment: Try Array.findIndex()

Comment: @Cooper, i'm searching the result of a consult on an API from Appsheet. The code is intended to decied if it's a new value(not found on the array) to add it and if it's found on the array to update/edit it.

Comment: I would just dive in and figure it out using the debugger.

Comment: Oh baseSistema is an array of objects.  That's your problem.  That's why indexOf() is not working for you.

Comment: You need to map all of the baseSistema.chamado into a single flat array and then that problem will go away.

Comment: just made this, but still not working. 

  var listaChamados = []

  for (var s = 0; s < baseSistema.length; s++){

    listaChamados = listaChamados.concat(baseSistema[s].Chamado)

  }

var registroNovo = listaChamados.indexOf(data[i][0]);

Comment: @Cooper, just got it!!! The variable that i wanna find is a number so i just had to cast it as a string using .toString() before i search on the array! Thanks for your help!! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just got it!!! The variable that i wanna find is a number so i just had to cast it as a string using .toString() before i search on the array!